# Swing/SWT Java error related to menu conflict

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing, swt

My developer updated a java application for me but neglected to include the build.xml when he sent the update.  Right now, when I debug as an application in Eclipse (OSX), the application interface pops up but is non clickable and returns the following to the console

```
2014-05-03 19:12:53.513 java[37325:d07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2014-05-03 19:12:53.514 java[37325:d07] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
2014-05-03 19:12:55.126 java[37325:d07] _createMenuRef called with existing principal MenuRef already associated with menu
2014-05-03 19:12:55.126 java[37325:d07] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9025625c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d95ce75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9025610c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff91a8fe84 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _createMenuRef] + 62
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff91a8f85a -[NSCarbonMenuImpl _instantiateCarbonMenu] + 143
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff91a8e022 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 876
    6   libswt-pi-cocoa-3740.jnilib         0x0000000113540b3d Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_OS_objc_1msgSendSuper__Lorg_eclipse_swt_internal_cocoa_objc_1super_2J + 89
    7   ???                                 0x0000000109164cd5 0x0 + 4447423701
)
Loading
Ready
```

When I last spoke with my developer he said he would re-send in a few days when he is back, but in the meantime he said I could just use the build.xml from the previous version and just delete djswing and SWT from the build.xml file, which he says was causing the error in the previous version.

Problem is there's nothing specific other than two lines referring to these.  Here's the code from build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
              Any modifications will be overwritten.
              To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
              directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="okc">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
    <property name="target" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="source" value="1.5"/>
    <path id="okc.classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/beansbinding-1.2.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/javax-jmi-reflect.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/toplink-essentials-agent.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="lib/toplink-essentials.jar"/>
    </path>
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="bin"/>
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
            <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.launch, **/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin"/>
    </target>
    <target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
    <target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
    <target name="build-subprojects"/>
    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="src"/>
             <classpath refid="okc.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
    <target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
        <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </copy>
        <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
            <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
        </unzip>
    </target>
    <target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
        <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
        <antcall target="build"/>
    </target>
    <target name="OkcApp">
        <java classname="okc.OkcApp" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
            <classpath refid="okc.classpath"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `-XstartOnFirstThread` option when you run the program. This should get the Display created on the correct thread.

Comment: No, that would have caused "Invalid thread access" exception. I too have the "_createMenuRef" error even though I'm running with `-XstartOnFirstThread`